# How to filter div in returned html output through ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, find, dynamic-html

Am creating a dynamic fields form with its settings like Label, Name, Id, Min, Max, Value.

When i click on button then a js function return the definition of text-box within two div.

Here returned HTML code:

```
<!--field div-->
<div id="text-field<?php echo $FieldId; ?>" class="new-field-div" onclick="activeSettings('text-field<?php echo $FieldId; ?>', 'text')">
    <p>Single Line Text</p>
    <input name="text-field<?php echo $FieldId; ?>" type="text" disabled />
</div>

<!--filed settings div-->
<div id="text-field-settings<?php echo $FieldId; ?>" class="new-field-div">
<p>Paragraph Field Label</p>
<input id="label-" name="label-" type="text"  />
<p>Field Size</p>
<select name="size-">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
<p>Charcter Range</p>
Min: <input id="min" name="min" type="text" value="0" style="width:50px;" />
Max: <input id="max" name="max" type="text" value="0" style="width:50px;" />
<p>Required: <input name="required" type="checkbox" value="yes" /> </p>
</div>
```

I want to filter both div individual using js.

I tried that:

```
function add_new_field(FormId, Type)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: "action=ufb_add_new_field&FormId=" + FormId + "&FieldType=" + Type,
        success:function(data){

            var div1 = jQuery(data).find('div#text-field1');

            var div2 = jQuery(data).find('div#text-field-settings1');

            //filter 1st div
            jQuery("#right-side-fields").append(div1);

            //filter 2nd div
            jQuery("#left-side-fields-settings").append(div2);
        }
    });
}
```

But no luck, need help or suggestion guys. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The type of data you receive is a string, you need to parse the html to get DOM nodes.

Check http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/

Try adding this at the begging of the success function.

```
data = $.parseHTML(data);
```

This would let you keep an array of DOM nodes instead of a string, so after wrapping it with jQuery object you should be able to find the divs you are looking for.

Comment: `var FieldDiv = jQuery(data).find("div#text-field"); var FieldSettingsDiv = jQuery(data).find("div#text-field-settings");` --Its retuning Array of object.-- `jQuery("#left-side-fields-settings").append(FieldSettingsDiv);`
Not rendering HTML div.

Comment: you can pick up the nodes with native javascript and use the appendChild method instead